# ROS Answers SE migration: launch rovio

Tags: ros, roslaunch, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a few more minutes to test things.  My rovio currently has no username or password.  I'd like to keep it that way.  I tried editing the launch file so that the values were "" but that seemed to generate an error.

Should I have them equal to nothing, to "", to blank space, to " " or what?

-Mike

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9127/launch-rovio/) by [mbahr](https://answers.ros.org/users/106/mbahr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Mike,

One method that works for me is to turn off user authentication in the Rovio web interface: click Settings->Security then uncheck the box next to Enable User Authentication and click the Update button.  With this done, you can put anything you want in the username and password fields in the rovio.launch file (like "foo" and "bar").

Another method is to add a Rovio user as a Guest (again via Settings->Security) and use a simple username and password; e.g. "foo" and "foobar" (password must be at least 6 characters) then use these in the rovio.launch file.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-02-20**:
Can you post the error you are getting? I don't get any errors and setting the username and password to  "" in rovio.launch works fine as long as user authentication is turned OFF on the Rovio.  If it is turned ON, I don't get any errors but cmd_vel commands are ignored (so the Rovio does not respond.)

**Comment by [mbahr](https://answers.ros.org/users/106/mbahr/) on 2011-02-19**:
Thanks for the reply.

I wanted to avoid having to enter anything.  I understand how to put in the information in the rovio, but wanted to keep it empty and learn how to enter null into the launch file.